# ARCore aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp, safe to ignore?

Tags: android, arcore

So on my ARCore class, everything works fine, but sometimes I get this error.

```
E/native: E1215 10:45:21.480590   20730 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:749] Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp: 599151873852
E/native: E1215 10:45:21.510649   20730 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:749] Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp: 599151915845
E/native: E1215 10:45:21.566573   20730 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:749] Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp: 599151957840
E/native: E1215 10:45:21.612423   20730 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:749] Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp: 599151999834
I/native: I1215 10:45:21.629322   20854 model_selector.cc:64] Keep using the lite model.
E/native: E1215 10:45:21.666847   20730 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:749] Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp: 599152041826
E/native: E1215 10:45:21.715095   20730 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:749] Not able to find preprocess rotation with expected timestamp: 599152083821
I/native: I1215 10:45:22.007947   20780 stationary_detector.cc:199] SensorFusion: Enter stationary state. Stability time: 1
```

(Included more of the debug log, maybe it's useful)
90% of the time it does nothing, sometimes it does not load my models, so I wonder what causes it? Is it safe to ignore?
It happens on models created by me on Blender or models from the internet.
When the model does not load, the error is as follows:

```
E/native: E1215 10:45:13.550989   20645 aimatter_landmarks_3Dmesh.cc:309] generic::invalid_argument: Graph has errors: 
    Packet timestamp mismatch on a calculator receiving from stream "model_select". Current minimum expected timestamp is 599144889572 but received 599144780124. Are you using a custom InputStreamHandler? Note that some InputStreamHandlers allow timestamps that are not strictly monotonically increasing. See for example the ImmediateInputStreamHandler class comment.
    Packet timestamp mismatch on a calculator receiving from stream "model_select". Current minimum expected timestamp is 599144889572 but received 599144780124. Are you using a custom InputStreamHandler? Note that some InputStreamHandlers allow timestamps that are not strictly monotonically increasing. See for example the ImmediateInputStreamHandler class comment.
    Packet timestamp mismatch on a calculator receiving from stream "model_select". Current minimum expected timestamp is 599144889572 but received 599144780124. Are you using a custom InputStreamHandler? Note that some InputStreamHandlers allow timestamps that are not strictly monotonically increasing. See for example the ImmediateInputStreamHandler class comment. [type.googleapis.com/mediapipe.StatusList='\n\xf0\x02\x08\x03\x12\xeb\x02Packet timestamp mismatch on a calculator receiving from stream \"model_select\". Current minimum expected timestamp is 599144889572 but received 599144780124. Are you using a custom InputStreamHandler? Note that some InputStreamHandlers allow timestamps that are not strictly monotonically increasing. See for example the ImmediateInputStreamHandler class comment.\n\xf0\x02\x08\x03\x12\xeb\x02Packet timestamp mismatch on a calculator receiving from stream \"model_select\". Current minimum expected timestamp is 599144889572 but received 599144780124. Are you using a custom InputStreamHandler? Note that some InputStreamHandlers allow timestamps that are not strictly monotonically increasing. See for example the ImmediateInputStreamHandler class comment.\n\xf0\x02\x08\x03\x12\xeb\x02Packet timestamp mismatch on a calculator receiving from stream \"model_select\". Current minimum expected timestamp is 599144889572 but received 599144780124. Are you using a custom InputStreamHandler? Note that some InputStreamHandlers allow timestamps that are not strictly monotonically increasing. See for example the ImmediateInputStreamHandler class comment.']
```

Should I be concerned?

Comment: Seeing the same error, created a [ticket on github](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-extensions/issues/70)

Comment: Thanks @Bersaelor, I saw that your ticket was closed, I'll update and check my side here if it also disappeared. Oh but I saw your ticket was for Unity, maybe Unity fixed it? I'll check it right now on Android Studio.

Comment: It seems it was a bug in earlier Unity interfaces to ARCore.